# Getting the context free grammer

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I am trying to get the a CFG for this. I got this:

L1={uv | u ∈Σ∗,v∈ Σ∗1Σ∗ and |v| ≤ |u|}

```
U -> A | B
A -> 0A | E
B -> 1B | E
V -> 1T | 0T | T
T -> G1
G -> I1 | I0 | E
```

Is this correct? **UAB** does the **u** section then **VTG** get the **v** part. Or am I completely doing it wrong?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Your grammar has no start symbol and there's no rule for the non-terminal $I$.

Answer (score 1):

I did not check your solution, but it doesn't look convincing. The reason is that the $u$ part is independent of the $v$ part, and so the constraint $|v|\le |u|$ cannot be enforced.

How about the following: (hint)

> rewrite the language as $L=\{ \alpha 1 \beta \mid |\alpha|\ge |\beta|+1\}$